# Can I use 'is' operator in a switch case in Dart?

Tags: dart, switch-statement

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I cant get it to work.

What I have:

```
if (current is classA){
   //do stuff
   return;
}
if (current is classB){
   //do stuff
   return;
}
if (current is classC){
   //do stuff
   return;
}
```

What I want:

```
switch (currentState) {
   case is classA: { 
      //do stuff
      break;
   }
   case is classB: { 
      //do stuff
      break;
   }
   case is classC: { 
      //do stuff
      break;
   }
}
```

What I really want (Kotlin):

```
When (currentState){
   is classA -> //do stuff
   is classB -> //do stuff
   is classC -> //do stuff
}
```

Is there anyway I can use the Dart Switch like the Kotlins When operator, or at least use other operators then == to assert the case evaluations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: Yes, now you can. Dart 3.0 introduced pattern matching, so now you can write:

```dart
switch (currentState) {
  case classA():
      //do stuff
  case classB():
      //do stuff
  case classC():
      //do stuff
}
```

You can also do much more, read about it here: https://dart.dev/language/patterns

The historical answer was:

> No.
>
> The Dart switch case is a very low-level construct. It allows only
> constant-value expressions that don't override operator `==`
> (except for a few basic platform types), so effectively it can be
> implemented using `identical` checks.

> There is no ability to do complicated checks, or checks on the type
> of the object, only identity checks.
>
> The recommended *pretty* way to do what you want is to have ClassA, > ClassB and ClassC all implement an interface with a `doStuff`
> member, and then do:
>
> ```dart
> currentState.doStuff()
> ```
>
> If that is not possible, you are back to the `if` sequence.

Comment: Ok, I'm using BLoC pattern in flutter and have to check witch State is being received.
Each state extends MyBlocState and determine what Widget-tree to build.

Judging by your answer there is no way to use a switch statement in this case.
Thanks for the answer and please correct me if I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: Same boat as Joel, this sucks :(

Comment: No longer the case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72727843/64505

Answer (score 6):

```
switch (runtimeType) {
   case ClassA: //do stuff 
      return;
   case ClassB: //do stuff
      return;
}
```

Comment: it's the most helpful answer
`switch (state.runtimeType) { ... }`

Comment: While this is one way to do it, note that the static analyzer won't be able to infer the more specific type like it can do with `if (x is X)` statements, meaning you might have to use `as` in the `case` clauses. In that case, `if` statements might be cleaner and less verbose

Comment: wrong, cause steel your have to cast your subtypes manuly, it's not like kotlin. steel you have to type (ClassA as SubtypeTarget).doSomthing(); or ...

Comment: Doesn't work for types like `int?`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the same syntax as in Kotlin but you can use *Freezed*.

https://pub.dev/packages/freezed

It allows you to use a similar syntax.

Considering this model:

```
@freezed
abstract class Model with _$Model {
  factory Model.first(String a) = First;
  factory Model.second(int b, bool c) = Second;
}
```

You can use when in the following way:

```
var model = Model.first('42');

print(
  model.when(
    first: (String a) => 'first $a',
    second: (int b, bool c) => 'second $b $c'
  ),
); // first 42
```